# JQuery - Clone multiple selected options - How can I check if exists?

Tags: jquery

I have a select list that contains a number of options. The user can select multiple options and 'assign' them to another select list. The problem I am having is how can I check to make sure one or more of the selected options are not part of the list being copied to? I understand I can use the following code to determine if a single value i.e. 'bar' exists in the other list, but how do I check if any of the multiple selected options exist?

```
var exists = false;
$('#select-box option').each(function(){
if (this.value == 'bar') {
    exists = true;
    return false;
}
});
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var otherBoxValues =  $('#other-select-box option').map(function(){ 
        return this.value;
    }); 

    var missingOptions = [];
    $('#select-box option').each(function(){ 
        if ($.inArray(this.value, otherBoxValues) > -1 ) {     
            missingOptions.push(this.value);
        } 
    }); 
   alert(missingOptions.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var exists = false;

$('#select-box option:selected').each(function(){
  if($("#target-select-box").find("option[value="+$(this).value+"]").length > 0){
        exists = true;
        return false;
  } 
});
```